# Calculating CHSH inequality violation in a two-qubit system with projective measurements

Tags: quantum-computing

Suppose a two-qubit system is in the state |Φ⟩ = (|00⟩ + |11⟩ )/ √2. Consider projective measurements with outcome ±1. Calculate the maximal violation of the CHSH inequality and find the measurement setting that can result the maximal violation.

I am new to quantum computing.I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Perhaps add some steps that you've taken to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the context of your question and what you've tried to solve it? This will help us shape a right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I's a tough one and one I struggled with too. Calculating the maximal violation of the CHSH inequality for the given two-qubit state |Φ⟩ = (|00⟩ + |11⟩ )/ √2, we need to consider four different measurement settings and compute the corresponding expectation values.

The CHSH inequality is expressed as follows:

CHSH = E(A, B) + E(A, B') + E(A', B) - E(A', B') ≤ 2,

where A, A' are the measurement settings for the first qubit there, and B, B' are the measurement settings for the second qubit, and E(A, B) is the expectation value for the measurement settings A and B. If that makes sense?

Now considering the four measurement settings:

Setting 1:
A = σz (measurement in the computational basis for the first qubit)
B = σz (measurement in the computational basis for the second qubit)

In this case, the expectation value E(A, B) can be calculated as follows:

E(A, B) = ⟨Φ|A ⊗ B|Φ⟩ = ⟨Φ|(σz ⊗ σz)|Φ⟩.

Expanding the tensor product and substituting |Φ⟩ = (|00⟩ + |11⟩ )/ √2:

E(A, B) = ⟨Φ|(σz ⊗ σz)|Φ⟩
= (1/√2)(⟨00|(σz ⊗ σz)|00⟩ + ⟨00|(σz ⊗ σz)|11⟩ + ⟨11|(σz ⊗ σz)|00⟩ + ⟨11|(σz ⊗ σz)|11⟩)
= (1/√2)(1 + 1 + 1 - 1)
= 2/√2
= √2.

Setting 2:
A = σx (measurement in the Hadamard basis for the first qubit)
B = σz (measurement in the computational basis for the second qubit)

In this case, the expectation value E(A, B) can be calculated as follows:

E(A, B) = ⟨Φ|A ⊗ B|Φ⟩ = ⟨Φ|(σx ⊗ σz)|Φ⟩.

Using the same steps as above, we find:

E(A, B) = -1/√2.

Setting 3:
A = σz (measurement in the computational basis for the first qubit)
B = σx (measurement in the Hadamard basis for the second qubit)

In this case, the expectation value E(A, B) can be calculated as follows:

E(A, B) = ⟨Φ|A ⊗ B|Φ⟩ = ⟨Φ|(σz ⊗ σx)|Φ⟩.

Using the same steps as above, we find:

E(A, B) = -1/√2.

Setting 4:
A = σx (measurement in the Hadamard basis for the first qubit)
B = σx (measurement in the Hadamard basis for the second qubit)

In this case, the expectation value E(A, B) can be calculated as follows:

E(A, B) = ⟨Φ|A ⊗ B|Φ⟩ = ⟨Φ|(σx ⊗ σx)|Φ⟩.

Using the same steps as above, we find:

E(A, B) = -√2.

Now, let's calculate the maximal violation of the CHSH inequality:

CHSH = E(A, B) + E(A, B') + E(A', B) - E(A', B')
= √2 + (-1/

Hope that helps you.